# Why does my function switching visibility if else statement not work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I am working on a project and I am supposed to use plain ol vanilla javaScript to hide one div and show another with two different link buttons. I have here what should work, but it keeps going in between forms and going back to the login form. What is going wrong? Excuse me for I am a noob at javaScript/coding and I am still learning in school. Thank you for your precious time <3 This will help me immensely as I have been crying for days as I feel like a failure for something so simple sounding.

```
function switchVisible() {
    if (document.getElementById('login1')) {

        if (document.getElementById('login1').style.display == 'none') {
            document.getElementById('login1').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('register1').style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('login1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('register1').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
}
function checkField(field) {
    if (!field.checkValidity()) {
        field.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
    } else {
        field.style.backgroundColor = '';
    }   
}
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    const form = document.getElementById('login-form');
    const emailField = form.logfield;
    const password = form.pw;
    const logLink = document.getElementById('logbtn');
    const regLink = document.getElementById('accountbtn');
    const form2 = document.getElementById('register-form');
    const emailField2 = form2.emailField2;
    const password2 = form2.pw2;
    const password3 = form2.pw3;

    emailField2.addEventListener('input', function() {
        checkField(emailField2);
    });
    password2.addEventListener('input', function() {
        checkField(password2);
    });
    password3.addEventListener('input', function() { 
        checkField(password3);
    });
    form2.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    checkField(emailField2);
    checkField(password2);
    checkField(password3);
    
    if(!form2.checkValidity(e)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Please fix form errors.');
    } else {
        alert('Form Submitted');
        }
    });
    emailField.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
        checkField(emailField);
    });
    password.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
        checkField(password);
    });
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    checkField(emailField);
    checkField(password);

    if(!form.checkValidity(e)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Please fix form errors.');
    } else {
        alert('Form Submitted');
        }
    });
});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="../normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../play2learn/login.js"></script>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <section>
            <h1>Play2Learn Logo</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul id="nav">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li class="contains"><a>Games</a>
                        <ul class="menu">
                            <li><a href="anagram-hunt.html">Anagram Hunt</a></li>
                            <li><a href="math-facts.html">Math Facts</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </section>
    </header>
    <hr>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<section id="login1">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form id="login-form" method="post" novalidate>
        <div>
            <label for="logfield">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="logfield" id="logfield" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="pw">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="pw" id="pw" size="15" required>
        </div>
        <div>
           <button type="submit" id="login-btn">LOGIN</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="" id="accountbtn" onclick="switchVisible();">Need an account? Register</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
<section id="register1">
    <h2>Register</h2>
    <form id="register-form" method="post" no validate>
        <div>
            <label for="email-field2">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email-field2" id="email-field2" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="pw2">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="pw2" id="pw2" size="15" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="pw3">Repeat Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="pw3" id="pw3" size="15" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" id="register-btn">REGISTER</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="" id="logbtn">Have an account? Log in</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
</div>
</body>
<hr>
<footer>&copy; 2022 Play2Learn</footer>
    <address>
            <a href="contact-us.html">
            <img src="images/email.png" alt="email-icon"></a>
            <a href="https://instagram.com">
            <img src="images/instagram.png" alt="instagram-icon"></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com">
            <img src="images/twitter-icon.png" alt="twitter-icon"></a>
            <a href="https://facebook.com">
            <img src="images/facebook-icon.png" alt="facebook-icon"></a>
    </address>
</body>
</html>
```

```
section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: .5rem .5rem;
}
h1 {
    color: #4FBDBA;
    margin: .5rem;
    padding: .5rem;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
body {
    background-color: #35858B;
}
nav {
    margin: 0 -0.5rem;
    padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
    display: inline;
    background: #4FBDBA;
    position: relative;

}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    color:rgb(53, 112, 132);
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: .5rem;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
nav a:hover {
    background: rgb(51, 136, 132);
}
nav a:active {
    color: teal;
}
li.contains ul {
    display: none;
}
li.contains:hover ul {
    background: #4FBDBA;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
li.contains li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
}
#clients h2 {
    color: rgb(30, 75, 90);
    margin: .5rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}
ul.menu a:hover {
    color: rgb(133, 202, 202);
    font-weight: bold;

}
a img {
    max-width: 32px;
    max-height: 32px;
    float: right;
}
footer {
    padding: .5rem;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}
address {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
}
address a {
    flex-flow: row;
}
hr {
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #AEFEFF;
    border: none;
    margin: auto;
}
#anagram {
    flex-flow: row;
    margin: 1rem;
    padding: 2rem;
    color: teal;
    text-align: center;
}
#math {
    flex-flow: row;
    margin: 1rem;
    padding: 2rem;
    color:#35858B;
    text-align: center;
}
div#about h2 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
p {
    color:white;;
    text-align: center;
}
label {
    display: block;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    color:#072227;
}
input {
    width: 97%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
textarea {
    width: 97%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
button#contact-btn,
button#login-btn, 
button#register-button {
    background-color:rgb(51, 136, 132);
    color: white;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: x-large;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

form {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
#about {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
#login1 {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
#register1 {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}
h2 {
    color: white;
}
section#math-facts {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by going in between forms? Which forms? Type out a step by step and explain what happens, thanks!

Comment: When you go to the login.html you will find a login form. On the very bottom it has a "Need an account? Register" link that in theory when clicked will hide the login form and show the register form. But what actually happens it it quickly shows the registration form and quickly goes right back to the login form. I would like it so that it doesnt do that and have it where the only time it will go back to the login form is when you are at the registration form on the very bottom it says "Have an account? Login" and when you click that it will hide the registration and show the login form.